# File upload fails with angularjs and spring boot

Tags: angularjs, spring-boot, file-upload

I want to upload file

controller.js

```
userService.saveProfile($scope.user.profile.companyLogo).then(function(response){
    if(response.status==201){
        $('#profileModal').hide();
        $scope.load();
    }
});
```

service.js

```
saveProfile:function(logo){
            var formData = new FormData();
            formData.append("file",logo);
            var retVal = $http({
                method : 'POST',
                url : '/api/user/profile',
                transformRequest: angular.identity,
                headers: {'Content-Type': undefined},
                data: formData
            }).then(function(response){
                return response;
            });
            return retVal;
        }
```

Controller.java

```
@RequestMapping(value="/profile",method = RequestMethod.POST,headers="'Content-Type':'multipart/form-data'")
    public ResponseEntity saveProfile(@RequestBody MultipartFile file){
        System.out.println(file);
        return new ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }
```

if I add headers to @RequestMapping I'm getting 404 and if I remove it I'm getting file null

Please suggest me the correct way of doing file upload

Comment: Are you getting the value of file inside the service?

Comment: @Vivz yes I'm getting value inside service

Comment: Is it going inside .then?

Comment: @Vivz then I try to post as form data to server but It's throwing 404 with headers on the server side

Comment: You have to specify the enctype="multipart/form-data" from angular js. http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-multipart-forms

Comment: @Sudhakar Tried that also but still the same it's setting content-type application/json;charset=UTF-8

Comment: You can add the below header and try       method: 'POST',
headers: {enctype:'multipart/form-data', Content-Type: undefined}

Comment: @Sudhakar yes now it's setting Content-Type to multipart/form-data but still throwing 404 with headers on the server side

Comment: 404 means your rest URL is wrong. Please check it or post your entire controller class.

Comment: no it's not wrong if i remove header from @RequestMapping then the control is coming there but the Multipart file is coming as null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked!

I removed headers from @RequestMapping and used @RequestPart instead of @RequestBody

```
@RequestMapping(value="/profile",method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity saveProfile(@RequestPart("file") MultipartFile file){
        System.out.println(file);
        return new ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }
```